# Can I access Spring-defined properties from within a Spring Condition?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

Hopefully my question is fairly self-explanatory - I will illustrate it with some example code.

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:/my-properties.properties")
public class SomeProperties {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    // private methods

    public boolean isEnabled(Foo foo) {
        // call private methods, call env.getProperty, return value
    }
}

@Component // it makes no difference whether it's there or not
public class MyCondition implements Condition {
    @Autowired // doesn't make a difference
    private SomeProperties someProperties;

    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        // ...
        boolean b = someProperties.isEnabled(foo); // get NPE on this line
        // ...return
    }
}

@Component
@Conditional(MyCondition.class)
public class Bar {
    // stuff
}
```

(Here I'm using Spring Boot to configure Spring. Although I doubt it makes any difference - as `@Component` beans are definitely accessible post-bootstrap, so it doesn't seem to be a problem in the way Spring is configured.)

The problem is that I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on the indicated line, because `someProperties` is `null`. This is presumably because at the time that the condition is run, the autowiring/instantiation phase of Spring bootstrap has not happened yet.

Is there any way to access Spring Properties in this way - like force Spring to load a bean before it normally would? Or is the only way to use standard Java / Apache Commons properties code as opposed to Spring?

Comment: Well, `presumably` it's something you should know. Is `SomeProperties` itself not being injected? Or are you getting the NPE in its `isEnabled` method, which we know nothing about? Is the Spring Framework instructed to process all the `@Component` annotations? So difficult to answer the question if you prune relevant code and you don't post the whole error trace...

Comment: (1) Is SomeProperties itself not being injected?: Yes, I believe it isn't. As I said in my question "...autowiring...has not happened yet". (2) I'm not getting the NPE in the isEnabled method, I'm getting the NPE on the line I said I was getting the NPE on, because someProperties == null. So there is no need for me to post the code of isEnabled, as it doesn't even get called. (3) Is Spring instructed to process @Component, not sure what you mean, I haven't explicitly instructed it to. (4) This is just example code to illustrate the problem statement, I haven't "pruned" anything.

Comment: Well, what you say in point (2) is not that clear in the question (because you're not providing the whole stack trace) so the best thing should be to edit your post and write down in the method that `someProperties` is reaching with `null` value. About Spring processing the `@Component` annotation, I mean that there's no reference to the way you configure Spring in your application. That's an important thing because it could be Spring itself not parsing the annotation and, in consequence, not creating the component itself, so not autowiring the field.

Comment: Ah okay. I'm using Spring Boot. I probably should have mentioned that. Regarding the point (2) above, I can't see any other way I could be getting an NPE on the line I mentioned other than if `someProperties == null`, but I will explicitly put that in the question as you say it's necessary.

Comment: `someProperties.isEnabled(foo)` could throw a NPE even `someProperties` not being null, cause `isEnabled` could internally throw it (for example, in case of `foo` being null). Good point to tell you're using Spring Boot, I've annotated the post with its tag ;-)

Comment: Yes, `isEnabled` could internally throw an NPE, but then the NPE would be on a line in `isEnabled`, rather than on the line specified. I didn't use the Spring Boot tag because I don't think my question is specific to Spring Boot. I just gave some example code from Spring, it doesn't matter how you configure Spring. The problem is that you can't access Spring Properties from inside a Spring Condition.